# Fourier Transform of $1-|x|$ for $|x|<1$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm having a little difficulty getting the right answer for this. So far I've got

$$F(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^0 (1+x)e^{-ikx}dx+ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty}(1-x)e^{-ikx}dx\\
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\bigg[ -\frac{1}{k^2}e^{ik} -\frac{1}{k^2}e^{-ik}+\frac{2}{k^2} \bigg]\\
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\bigg( \frac{e^{ik / 2}}{ik} - \frac{e^{-ik/2}}{ik} \bigg)^2\\
=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\sin^2({k/2})}{k^2}$$

And the question wants to to evaluate using Parseval's theorem $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^4({k/2})}{k^4} $$
For which I get $$\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty(1-x)^2dx = \frac{\pi}{6} $$
The actual answer is supposed to be $\frac{\pi}{24}$ so I'm not sure where I went wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You lost a factor of two when squaring $e^{it}-e^{-it}=2i\sin t$. Fixing this gives
$$F(k)=\frac2\pi\frac{\sin^2(k/2)}{k^2}.
$$
The lost factor of $2$ becomes a factor of $4$ when $F$ gets squared. Parseval's theorem then yields
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^4({k/2})}{k^4}=\frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^\infty(1-x)^2dx = \frac{\pi}{24}.
$$